# Singular integral operators acting on Zygmund class

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

It is proven in "Classical and Modern Fourier Analysis" by L. Grafakos (Corollary 6.7.2) that if a kernel $K(x)$ defined away from the origin on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies

$$\sup_{0<R<\infty}\frac{1}R \int_{|x|\leq R}|K(x)||x|dx\leq C$$
$$\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}}\int|K(x-y)-K(x)|dx\leq C$$
$$\sup_{0<R_1<R_2<\infty}\left|\int_{R_1<|x|<R_2} K(x)dx\right|\leq C$$

for some finite constant C, then for all $f$ in the Schwartz space and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{result}
\left\|P.V. \int K(x-y)f(y)dy\right\|_{\dot{B}^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}}\leq C'\|f\|_{\dot{B}^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}}, 
\end{equation}
where $\dot{B}^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}$ denotes the Homogeneous Besov-Lipschitz spaces.

For $0<\alpha<1,$ $\|f\|_{\dot{B}^\alpha_{\infty,\infty}}$ is equivalent with the well known Hölder seminorm involving differences ($\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\; h\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)|}{|h|^\alpha} $). In this case, the proof of \eqref{result} can easily be done using differences (as done in, for instance, "Vorticity and Incompressible Flow" by A. Majda and A. Bertozzi, Chapter 4).

For $\alpha=1,$ $\|f\|_{\dot{B}^1_{\infty,\infty}}$ is equivalent to the Zygmund semi-norm given by second order differences $$\sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n,\; h\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}}\frac{|f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)|}{|h|}. $$
I have been trying to proof \eqref{result} for $\alpha=1$ using second order differences and following the scheme of "Vorticity and Incompressible Flow" but I am not succeding at all. Does anyone know any reference where this could be done using differences?

I know that using second order differences for defining the Zygmund class is not very practical and that there are lots of multiple definitions for this class. However, I would like to have a proof of the above result done with this particular definition.

Thanks in advance!